# Move between different workspaces efficiently

Tags: gnome, workspaces, productivity

Using GNOME here, I want to switch between different workspaces more efficiently -- by this I mean, suppose I am on `workspace #1` and I want to switch to `workspace #3` ... how do I that efficiently? The technique I follow is by pressing `Ctrl + Left Arrow` twice, which is highly unproductive.

I am guessing there is a better way and hopefully without installing an external software (on Debian).

Comment: What's `efficiently` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `gnome-control-center` to assign keyboard shortcuts to the different desktops. Depending on the version of GNOME you use the item will probably be named differently. On GNOME 2.32 it's called *Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Answer (score 0):

If using GNOME 3, you can try installing the [workspace indicator extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/).